# Unable to access volume

Tags: mount, ntfs

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 in my Acer Aspire A315,51 i3 64-bit alongside Windows 10. When I start my computer, I have to choose Windows 10 or Ubuntu. It was working good, then I got a problem in Ubuntu, that it cannot access the hard disk. When I press on the hard disk it gives me this error:

```
Unable to access volume. 
Error mounting /dev/sda4 at media/f/volume.
command line mount -t "ntfs" -o
```

Comment: What happened before this issue?

Comment: "Hibernated" or "Quick Boot" Windows partitions are in some Windows-secret strange state. Ubuntu can't

Comment: Could you please add a little more detail? What *exactly* did you do, what did you expect to happen and what happened instead? Did you encounter any warning or error messages? Please reproduce them *in their entirety* in your question. You can select, copy and paste terminal content and most dialogue messages in Ubuntu. Please **[edit]** your post to add information instead of posting a comment. (see [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask))

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Answer (score 1):

This is caused by Windows 10 not doing a true shutdown so the partition is marked as still in use. You can mount the partition as read only with the `mnt` command.

```
sudo mount -o ro /dev/sda4 /mnt
```

Or log back into Windows and from the command prompt run

```
shutdown /r /f /t 0
```

This will force windows to perform a full shutdown instead of the hybrid shutdown.

Answer (score 1):

Brownm's answer is exactly right about the cause, but his solution is only good for a single shutdown. If you switch frequently there's an easier long-term solution buried in the Control Panel.

1. From your control panel navigate to "System and Security" and then "Power Options"
2. Click the link labeled "Change what the power button does" in the sidebar.
3. Click the link labeled "Change settings that are currently unavailable"
4. Uncheck the box that says "Fast startup"

Answer (score 0):

I think this would work

```
sudo ntfsfix /dev/sda4
```